# Looking for a kafka connector to upsert datas to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, logstash, apache-kafka-connect

Is there any kafka connector that can handle this kind of requests please ?

I receive datas in a kafka topic in this format (Number of rows inside the JSON are random):

```
{
"1574922337":[{"price": 1, "product": 2], 
"1574922338":[{"price": 13, "product": 5}], 
"1574922339":[{"price": 0.2, "product": 1}]
}
```

I want from the kafka connector to parse this JSON event message received from the topic in order to create 3 documents at a time with `id=TIMESTAMP`, and this using `UPSERT` (If `id` already exists, we update it only, if not exists it will be added).

Do you have an approach for this please or references ?

Or any open source connector that can be easy to compile using MAVEN, will make some changes on it to adapt it for this kind of request.

Waiting your help please.

Comment: If you say you are willing to modify code, then the existing Elasticsearch connector doesn't work for you?

Comment: @cricket_007 I am facing compilation errors using `confluentinc/kafka-connect-elasticsearch`, I posted an issue in the github repo but without answer since 1 month now. I used https://docs.lenses.io/connectors/sink/elastic6.html, but it's build using scala and not familiar with it (The basic setup is working and can insert datas, but not like the format needed and posted here). Thank you

Comment: You need to checkout a release tag of the Confluent connector for it to build. Master branch will not build without also compiling trunk Kafka  source code

Comment: Much easier than modify anything, I'd use Logstash with a `kafka` input to read messages and then split the messages into individual ones inside filters and finally leverage the `elasticsearch` output which knows how to do upserts. No code, just configuration

Comment: @Val I already thought about it... since I am using many connectors for my projects and all inside a same folder without any third party program, I want to stay on this and do the same also for ES, thank you for your suggestion :)

Comment: @cricket_007 Do you have any compilation instructions about it ? I just downloaded the repository and tried to compile using MAVEN. (By the way, The official JAR not worked with me, its for this I am looking to compile it my self in order to get dependency JAR files - I suppose the problem comes from here).

Comment: Should just be `git checkout v5.3.1-post; mvn clean package`, but I second the Logstash opinion given that the Elasticsearch Kafka Connect does not do upserts

Comment: @cricket_007 Since they do not support upsert this will take more time for me to add this feature ... do you have a config for logstash to filter this json please ? or any close example to demonstrate the process ? thanks again

Comment: I've not used logstash recently. Maybe @Val knows how to do it

Comment: @cricket_007 Thank you sir :)

Comment: I have something that does that somewhere, just need to find out where... stay tuned

Comment: @Val Big thanks, take your time sir :)

Comment: Note the [updated answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61561257/6952495). You simply need to add this to the Kafka ES Connector config: `write.method=upsert`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here goes. As I suggested, it should work pretty well by leveraging Logstash with:

- a [`kafka` input](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-kafka.html) to read messages
- a [`ruby` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-ruby.html) to slice and dice the message into several events
- an [`elasticsearch` output](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html) to perform upserts

The main Logstash configuration follows:

```
input {
  kafka {
    bootstrap_servers => "..."
    topic_id => "message_topic"
    auto_offset_reset => "smallest"
    reset_beginning => true
  }
}
filter {
  mutate {
    remove_field => ["@timestamp", "@version", "host"]
  }
  ruby {
    path => "/path/to/split.rb"
  }
  mutate {
    remove_field => ["@timestamp", "@version"]
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "https://..."
    http_compression => true
    index => "product_index"
    document_id => "%{id}"
    document_type => "type_name"
    action => "update"
    doc_as_upsert => true
  }
}
```

The ruby code in `split.rb` is pretty simple. What is does is iterate over each timestamp and for each element of the array that timestamp points to, it creates a new event with the timestamp as the `id` field.

```
def register(params)
end

def filter(event)
  events = []
  event.to_hash.each do |timestamp,array|
    array.each do |sub| 
      subEvent = LogStash::Event.new(sub)
      subEvent.set('id', timestamp)
      events << subEvent
    end
  end
  return events
end
```

Basically, what it produces for the sample message you gave above is the following:

```
{"id":"1574922337","product":2,"price":1}
{"id":"1574922339","product":1,"price":0.2}
{"id":"1574922338","product":5,"price":13}
```